# Break URL failing with escaped % sign in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using the following lines in my preamble to force long URLs in the bibliography to be broken, this is working mostly successfully however it doesn't seem to be working on an entry where I have had to escape percent signs.

```
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, breaklinks=true}
```

Bibliography entry

```
@online{talex,
 title = {{Comprehensive Talos examples}},
 year = {2019},
 url = {https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/autonomio/talos/blob/master/examples/Hyperparameter\%20Optimization\%20with\%20Keras\%20for\%20the\%20Iris\%20Prediction.ipynb}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the `xurl` package on your system. If so, load it instead of `url`, don't load the `breakurl` package, and get rid of the `def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}` package.

Comment: I have installed the `xurl` package and removed the other lines but the error still seems to be persisting.

Comment: I should also mention I am using `natbib`

Comment: Most bibliography styles that support a `url` field support it in a way that does not require you to escape `%` with a backslash if the `url` and/or `hyperref` package is loaded. I wouldn't load `breakurl` and would instead try `xurl` if the normal `url` doesn't break properly. But we can only give more specific advice if you can turn the two code snippets into a fully working example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).